# Symfony form_widget() in Twig gives <input> wrapped in a <div> (with jQuery and jQuery-mobile)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, symfony-forms, symfony

For this case, let's pretend I implement a form with the official example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

At the "Rendering each Field by Hand" title, I want to add some attribute in the twig file so all my fields are evenly placed on a row by using "col-* css" manner to occupy space on a row.

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
<div class="col-12">
    {{ form_label(form.task,null,{'label_attr': {'class':'col-3'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.task, {'attr': {'class': 'col-4' }}) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.task, {'attr': {'class': 'col-5'}}) }}
</div>

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

With that example, the rendering of form_widget will be:

```
<div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
    <input type="text" id="task_task" name="task[task]" required="required" class="col-4">
</div>
```

One notices that **"col-4"** class attribute is in the `input` tag but since this tag is **surrounded by a `div`** the display is not as expected and the **"col-4" should be indeed in the `div` tag which is the parent of the `input` tag** so as to have the "col-4" rule applying on the screen.

So I wonder if there is a way with the symfony form to transfer the class attribute of the `input` set with Twig function form_widget() to its parent `div` instead of going with the jQuery  javascript function to fix the DOM display?

Comment: I'm almost certain that there's a way to do this. Just let me find it, and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @FighterJet I did a workaround: {% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}  and then edited {% block form_row  %} and each block inside: {% block form_label   %}, {% block ****_widget %}, {% block form_errors %}. In each of the block edited inside form_row I start by <div class="col-[1<length<12 ]"> and form_row first instruction is <div class="col-12">. It does the job.

Comment: Okay, if that works for you, then I won't bother (to tell you the truth, I couldn't find an answer anyway). Please post that as a self-answer, though, and mark it as the solution. (Remember to use code formatting.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a workaround by creating a template file that redefines the form **input_inline_template.twig.html**.

As one can see it edits the **form_div_layout.html.twig** which can be found in the [main form themes file](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig).

The block `{% block form-widget %}` can be substituted with various cases depending on the widget wanted.

You can then use this file by entering: `{% form_theme form 'YourBundle:[folder to file]:input_inline_template.html.twig' %}`.

```
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %} 
{% block form_row  %}
    <div class='col-12' id={{ id ~ '_div_row_id'}}>
    {% block form_label   %}
        <div class='col-3' id={{ id ~ '_div_label_id' }}>
            {{ parent() }}
        </div>
    {% endblock %}

        {% block form-widget %}
            <div class='col-4'>
                {{ parent() }}  
            </div>
        {% endblock %}

    {% block form_errors %}
        <div class='col-5'>

            {%- if errors|length > 0 -%} 
                {%- for error in errors -%}
                    <div id={{ id ~ "_error_msg_id" }}>{{ error.message }}</div>
                {%- endfor -%}
            {%- endif -%} 
        </div>
    {% endblock %}

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```